# Reset Custom JavaScript drop-down list Without Page Refersh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select) code in order to customize a drop-down list Selector. 
Is there a way I can reset this code without having to reload the page by calling a function by pressing a button.

```
<button onclick="reset();">Reset</button>
```

Ex. If "Jaguar" is selected, when the button is pressed, the selected element should change back to the orginal "Select car:" 0 option.

```
reset = function() {

  // Set default option to "Select car:" (0)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reseting, what you want is to put the first `option` text into the `select-selected` div (which is the one that shows the current selected option) and also update the `select` selected index.

Also, you want to remove `same-as-selected` class from the selected div:

```
function reset() {
    var customSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select")[0];
    var select = customSelect.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    var selected = customSelect.getElementsByClassName("select-selected")[0];
    var selectedItem = customSelect.getElementsByClassName('same-as-selected')[0];

    select.selectedIndex = 0;
    selected.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    selectedItem.classList.remove('same-as-selected');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This resets the `div class select-selected`, but the old option is still selected in the drop down list. https://jsfiddle.net/xpfv5cbL/

Comment: I updated the code to correct the behaviour you commented.